# Can I model imported CAD stl files

Tags: objects, import, blend-files

I want to import a CAD drawing in STL format, because it seems easier than trying to Model the drawing in Blender.

I am unable to work with the surface textures, colors, and details to make it look real.

Is there a way in Blender to work with an imported STL file?

Comment: So the model imported ok? but the materials aren't imported properly or you just can't create any textures that look good?